# How to exclude an array of objects from mongoose find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Lets pretend my collection holds following elements:

```
const Item = mongoose.Schema({
   type: { type: String },
   group: { type: Number }
});

[
   { type: "A", group: 1 },
   { type: "B", group: 1 },
   { type: "C", group: 1 },
   { type: "A", group: 2 },
   { type: "B", group: 2 },
   { type: "C", group: 2 },
]
```

Now I want to execute a `find` operation but want to exclude following items:

```
const items = [
    { type: "A", group: 1 },
    { type: "B", group: 1 },
];

const result = await Model.find({ /* ??? */ });
```

How does the query have to look to get the following response?

```
const result = [
   { type: "C", group: 1 },
   { type: "A", group: 2 },
   { type: "B", group: 2 },
   { type: "C", group: 2 },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$nor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator, performs a logical NOR operation on an array of one or more query expression and selects the documents that fail all the query expressions in the array.

```
const items = [
    { type: "A", group: 1 },
    { type: "B", group: 1 },
];
const result = await Model.find({ $nor: items });
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V7q39MZvGeA)